# How can I determine the compiler which processes a header file?

Tags: ubuntu, compile, gcc, clang

I want to compile a C/C++ project in an Ubuntu environment. My problem is that at some point it encounters a header file where `__stdc_version__` is not defined and since both `-Werror` and `-Wundef` are being set, it throws an error. Unfortunately, I don't directly invoke the compiler or use a Makefile. Instead, some compiler is invoked through an incredibly complex chain of Makefiles and Bash scripts and maybe more. That being said, for any practical purposes I have virtually no control over the compiler flags being used. However, compilation is supposed to work and I suspect the issue to be related to the installations of the various compilers present on the machine.

My question is now the following: How can I determine the executable that processes the header file, where compilation crashes?

Any solution is appreciated. Could also be a way to make the compiler stuck in an infinite computation loop, so that the executable can be determined using `htop`.

Comment: Do you know the exact name/path of the header file?

Comment: @user1686 Yes, I do.

Comment: "since both -Werror and -Wundef are being set, it throws an error".. defined by WHO?  Also, you probably just need to redefine them in your code before the other stuff gets hit.. something like [this page](https://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/200894-ok-define-__stdc_version__) shows.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas With all due respect, but I think you either did not thoroughly read my question or ignored the fact that my question is not about the problem that I have, but rather about an approach to solve it. I provided some background information about my real problem to add context, but from both my question and the questions title it should be clear that my question is about finding the executable which processes a header file and not about an issue related to `__stdc_version__`.

Comment: Should `__stdc_version__` be defined for the compilation? Is the error only written to stderr, or is also an error file being produced?

Comment: @harrymc The error is only written to stderr. I'll put it this way. Compilation worked on a different machine, which I don't have access to though. Also, it's very unlikely that the build files on that machines differed in any way from those on mine. The usage of `__stdc_version__` in the particular header file is of minor relevance. Hence, I can't tell whether `__stdc_version__` should be defined or not, since compilation is likely to work without `-Werror`, but that's not really relevant, because as I mentioned before, I don't have control over the compilation flags.

Comment: With all due respect .. DOUGH! .. sorry. :P .. only trying to help.

Comment: Wild idea: Use the syntax `command 2> >(xargs -n1 script)`, where the script checks for the compiler error message and then pauses everything (perhaps by `read -p`).

Comment: @harrymc Thank you for the idea. I think I don't understand what you propose though. If I do `python -c "import sys; print('hello',file=sys.stderr);print('world',file=sys.stderr);print('exit')" 2> >(xargs -n1 bash -c "read -p 'prompt:'; echo ${REPLY}_ > out"; for ((;;)) { sleep 1 ; })`, then it prints `exit` to stdout, writes `hello_` to out. However, the way I understand your idea, it's supposed to write `hello_` to out, but remain stuck in the first process and never reach the `print('exit')` statement?

Comment: Seems like the idea has some merit, just that `read -p` is not the right method to suspend the script. Perhaps simply do `ps T` to get the list of processes associated with this terminal.